# petl convert data from duplicate entries

Tags: python, etl, petl

Am trying to use `petl` library to build an ETL process that copied data between two tables. The table contain a unique `slug` field on the destination. For that, I wrote my script so It would identify duplicate slugs and convert them with by appending `ID` to the slug value.

```
    table = etl.fromdb(source_con, 'SELECT * FROM user')
    # get whatever remains as duplicates
    duplicates = etl.duplicates(table, 'slug')
    for dup in [i for i in duplicates.values('id')]:
        table = etl.convert(
            table,
            'slug',
            lambda v, row: '{}-{}'.format(slugify_unicode(v), str(row.id).encode('hex')),
            where=lambda row: row.id == dup,
            pass_row=True
        )
```

The above did not work as expected, it seems like the `table` object remains with duplicate values after the loop.

Anyone can advise? 
Thanks